Can't load my model using load_state_dict: RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for UNetGenerator: Unexpected key(s) in state_dict
I am using Kaggle to train my my Pix2pix GAN model
however I had to save every 12 hr. the checkpoints and continue the train again
The problem is when i want to load my model
generator.load_state_dict(checkpoint['generator_state_dict'])

discriminator.load_state_dict(checkpoint['discriminator_state_dict'])

gen_optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_G_state_dict'])

disc_optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_D_state_dict'])

the following error show
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:2215, in Module.load_state_dict(self, state_dict, strict, assign)
   2210         error_msgs.insert(
   2211             0, 'Missing key(s) in state_dict: {}. '.format(
   2212                 ', '.join(f'"{k}"' for k in missing_keys)))
   2214 if len(error_msgs) > 0:
-> 2215     raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
   2216                        self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
   2217 return _IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys, unexpected_keys)

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for UNetGenerator:
    Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "down2.1.weight", "down2.1.bias", "down2.1.running_mean", "down2.1.running_var", "down2.1.num_batches_tracked", "down3.1.weight", "down3.1.bias", "down3.1.running_mean", "down3.1.running_var", "down3.1.num_batches_tracked", "down4.1.weight", "down4.1.bias", "down4.1.running_mean", "down4.1.running_var", "down4.1.num_batches_tracked", "down5.1.weight", "down5.1.bias", "down5.1.running_mean", "down5.1.running_var", "down5.1.num_batches_tracked", "down6.1.weight", "down6.1.bias", "down6.1.running_mean", "down6.1.running_var", "down6.1.num_batches_tracked", "down7.1.weight", "down7.1.bias", "down7.1.running_mean", "down7.1.running_var", "down7.1.num_batches_tracked", "up1.1.weight", "up1.1.bias", "up1.1.running_mean", "up1.1.running_var", "up1.1.num_batches_tracked", "up2.1.weight", "up2.1.bias", "up2.1.running_mean", "up2.1.running_var", "up2.1.num_batches_tracked", "up3.1.weight", "up3.1.bias", "up3.1.running_mean", "up3.1.running_var", "up3.1.num_batches_tracked", "up4.1.weight", "up4.1.bias", "up4.1.running_mean", "up4.1.running_var", "up4.1.num_batches_tracked", "up5.1.weight", "up5.1.bias", "up5.1.running_mean", "up5.1.running_var", "up5.1.num_batches_tracked", "up6.1.weight", "up6.1.bias", "up6.1.running_mean", "up6.1.running_var", "up6.1.num_batches_tracked", "up7.1.weight", "up7.1.bias", "up7.1.running_mean", "up7.1.running_var", "up7.1.num_batches_tracked".

and I am using InstanceNorm2d in both generator and Discriminator however if i change it to batchnorm2d it will be load it but I am using InstanceNorm2d  and i am sure that there is no mismatches between checkpoints and my model
the following is the generator and Discriminator   that i am using
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class UNetGenerator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_channels, output_channels):
        super(UNetGenerator, self).__init__()

        def down_block(in_channels, out_channels, normalization=True):
            layers = [nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1)]
            if normalization:
                layers.append(nn.InstanceNorm2d(out_channels))
            layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True))
            return nn.Sequential(*layers)

        def up_block(in_channels, out_channels, dropout=False):
            layers = [nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
                      nn.InstanceNorm2d(out_channels),
                      nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            if dropout:
                layers.append(nn.Dropout(0.5))
            return nn.Sequential(*layers)

        # Encoder
        self.down1 = down_block(input_channels, 64, normalization=False)
        self.down2 = down_block(64, 128)
        self.down3 = down_block(128, 256)
        self.down4 = down_block(256, 512)
        self.down5 = down_block(512, 512)
        self.down6 = down_block(512, 512)
        self.down7 = down_block(512, 512)
        self.down8 = down_block(512, 512, normalization=False)

        # Decoder
        self.up1 = up_block(512, 512, dropout=True)
        self.up2 = up_block(1024, 512, dropout=True)
        self.up3 = up_block(1024, 512, dropout=True)
        self.up4 = up_block(1024, 512)
        self.up5 = up_block(1024, 256)
        self.up6 = up_block(512, 128)
        self.up7 = up_block(256, 64)
        self.up8 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, output_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        # Encoder
        d1 = self.down1(x)
        d2 = self.down2(d1)
        d3 = self.down3(d2)
        d4 = self.down4(d3)
        d5 = self.down5(d4)
        d6 = self.down6(d5)
        d7 = self.down7(d6)
        d8 = self.down8(d7)

        # Decoder with skip connections
        u1 = self.up1(d8)
        u2 = self.up2(torch.cat([u1, d7], dim=1))
        u3 = self.up3(torch.cat([u2, d6], dim=1))
        u4 = self.up4(torch.cat([u3, d5], dim=1))
        u5 = self.up5(torch.cat([u4, d4], dim=1))
        u6 = self.up6(torch.cat([u5, d3], dim=1))
        u7 = self.up7(torch.cat([u6, d2], dim=1))
        u8 = self.up8(torch.cat([u7, d1], dim=1))
        
        return u8
class PatchGANDiscriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_channels):
        super(PatchGANDiscriminator, self).__init__()

        def discriminator_block(in_channels, out_channels, normalization=True):
            layers = [nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1)]
            if normalization:
                layers.append(nn.InstanceNorm2d(out_channels))
            layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True))
            return nn.Sequential(*layers)

        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            discriminator_block(input_channels * 2, 64, normalization=False),  # Input and target concatenated
            discriminator_block(64, 128),
            discriminator_block(128, 256),
            discriminator_block(256, 512),
            nn.Conv2d(512, 1, kernel_size=4, padding=1)  # Final output, no normalization --- check
        )

    def forward(self, input_image, target_image):
        # Concatenate input and target along the channel axis
        x = torch.cat((input_image, target_image), 1)
        return self.model(x)

The problem is that because i am using InstanceNorm2d

Did you initially save those weights with a model with batch norm or instance norm?

man i said it , i save it  with  instance norm

Why did you mention batch norm then?
